# Electron issue after updating electron and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

I have a small electron project which I've just updated (Electron, typescript etc)...

This is the code that's breaking:

```
dialog.showOpenDialog({}, (files) => {
    if(files && files.length > 0) {
      fs.readFile(files[0], 'utf8', (err, res) => {
        if (!err) {
          editor.setModel(monaco.editor.createModel(res, 'javascript'));
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

It doesn't like the `{}` after `dialog.showOpenDialog(`

The error I'm getting is:

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BrowserWindow'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `showOpenDialog` is used differently, probably you updated from a quite old electron version and they changed it. Now it takes an optional browserWindow and an options object and returns a promise (shown with the async/await syntax):

```
  const {canceled, files, bookmarks} = await dialog.showOpenDialog({});
```

Reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options